# Does $Spin(n,m)$ double cover only $SO(n,m)^+$

Tags: lie-groups, covering-spaces, spin-geometry

Subtleties like this are often glossed over in physics texts so I thought I'd ask here.  Again, Does $Spin(n,m)$ double cover only the component of $SO(n,m)$ connected to the identity (often denoted in physics as $SO(n,m)^+$ ?

NOTE:
Albanese's answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2281786/universal-cover-of-the-lorentz-group-in-n-dimensions?rq=1) addresses my question and mostly answers it.

Comment: $SO(n)$ is connected; perhaps (since you mention physics) you wanted $SO(n,1)$

Comment: @user8268  Yes, apologies, I was being sloppy, I'm used to working in $SO(n,\mathbb{C})$ where the various indefinite assigments are all isomorphic.

Comment: $SO(n,\mathbb C)$ is connected too

Comment: @user8268  that's obvious by the fact they're isomorphic.   It's common to consider the complexification of such groups for manipulation purposes then, in the end, reduce to the particular real representation that you're dealing with (at least that's how I learned).  This is how Wick rotations work for example.  However by Albanese's answer (linked above) I guess not even the $Spin(n,m)$ groups (yes over $\mathbb{R}$ ) are connected in general.

Comment: As you can see in the linked answer, standard usage of $\operatorname{Spin}(p,q)$ is as the double cover of $\operatorname{SO}(p,q)$ so it is only as connected as $\operatorname{SO}(p,q)$ is and moreover its connected components are not even simply connected in general, since it is not always the universal cover (which instead looks like $\operatorname{Spin}(p)\times \operatorname{Spin}(q)\times \mathbb{R}^{pq}$)

Comment: Some people choose to define $\operatorname{Spin}(p, q)$ as a double cover of the identity component of $SO(p, q)$ ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin_group#Indefinite_signature) for example), but the definition via Clifford algebras naturally double covers $SO(p, q)$ as I mentioned in the answer you linked to.